# How do I calculate errors in a tkinter typing test?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a tkinter typing test in Python, and I have run into problems with getting the input, and then calculating the errors based on that input. There is a method that was given to me when I asked a previous question about the app, but there is still something wrong. There is no error message, and I can't figure out why the error and wpm results are way off.
Here is the code

```
def main_screen():
    start_time=time.time()
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title('Typing Test')
    tk.geometry('800x500')
    base_text=Label(tk,text=randomizer(),bg='#E0E0EE',font=('Arial',14),wraplength=700,justify=LEFT)
    base_text.pack(pady=10)
    text_area=Text(tk,font=('Arial',14),width=63,height=7,wrap='word')
    text_area.pack()
    tk.update()
#WPM Calculation
    target_text=randomizer()
    typed_text=[]
    wpm=0
    errors=0
    def get_key(event,list):
        list.append(event.char)
        print(list)
    text_area.bind('<KeyPress>',lambda _: get_key(_,typed_text))
    typed_text.clear()
    while True:
        tk.update()
        time_elapsed=max(time.time()-start_time,1)
        if time_elapsed>=60:
            break

for x in typed_text:
    if x != target_text:
        errors += 1
print(wpm)
print(errors)
```

The print statements are just to make the output clear. I need a way to delete the first empty string in the list. A different way of calculating errors and wpm is also appreciated. I just need to finish this project.

I tried using `typed_text.pop(0)`, `typed_text.pop(-1)`, and `typed_text.clear()`, but none of them worked for deleting the empty string.

Comment: You can compute the errors with `errors = sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(typed_text,target_text))`.  To do words-per-minute, you need a definition of "words".  5 characters is often used in standard tests.

Comment: Add `if event.char:` as the first line in `get_key`.  That way, you won't keep any non-key events.

Comment: See [ask]. Also you need to provide a [mre] with debugging details including logs, input data, etc. Anyway, why not use ```text_area.get('1.0', 'end')```?